# Print current line of text file to previous line of text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that I'm trying to process. The data is in the form of:

```
1002001             1             1             1             1                1
+                   1        1.0e-4       1.24012        1.0e-4          0.44
+              1.0e-4          0.44           1.0           0.0           1.0
+                 0.0           1.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
+                 0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
```

I would like to take all the lines that start with `+` and move them to the line that starts with '1002001', like this (kind of like `sed -r ':a;N;s/\n^\+//g;ba`):

```
1002001 1 1 1 1 1 1 1.0e-4 1.24012 1.0e-4 0.44 1.0e-4 0.44 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Do you just want to join the lines, or do you also want to collapse the whitespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(Get-Content yourfile.txt -Raw) -replace '[\r\n]+\+', ''
```